# Setting up auth0 and NESTJS with no front end

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, auth0, identity-management

I am currently building a backend service for a project. I have set it up with auth0 but am having some dificulties wrapping my head around the flow of stuff.

Since their is no front end, how will my backend recieve jwt tokens in my requests?

I know there is a way to get this up so that there is a default one in postman, but im struggeling to put all the pieces together.

I want to create a user DB based on the sub feild of the decrypted jwt token, but am not sure how to abtract it really?

Ive worked on features before, but the set up had always been done by someone else.

I am reading documentation, but don't think I know where to look for the exact answers.

any tips, pointers or links would be greatly appreciated

what I have done:
Setting up Auth0 and Nestjs with auth0's tutorial front end, though it means I cant look into that they've done.

Comment: Have you tried `machine-to-machine (M2M)` tokens? It sounds like that's the one you need. Check out this article for details: https://auth0.com/blog/using-m2m-authorization/

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) to "catch" all incoming requests or perhaps a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) is what you need. I am using AWS Cognito + postman (no front end) - I can provide an example(s) if this is similar...

Comment: Hi, thankyous os much for your reply, I wasn't clear so I apologise, we will have a front end in the future, but we are building the backend API first, so right now there is no front end to route login requests too. I'm having trouble trying to have a fake front end Authentification running in my backend so that I can go ahead and get authorisation for different features/ routes and also so I can start mapping the sub from the token_id to user entities. Douse this make it any more clear?